# VB6 sempre executa a 2ª função mesmo a 1ª sendo Falsa

Tags: c#, visual-basic-6

O `if` no VB6 executa sempre a 2ª função mesmo validando que a 1ª é `False`, o C# não executa a 2ª função no caso da 1ª já ser false.

Como posso colocar o vb6 a executar a 2ª função, apenas se a 1ª for verdadeira?

**Código c#:**

```
if(CalculoHora() && ValidaDados())
{}
```

**Código VB6:**

```
if (CalculoHora and ValidaDados) then

end if
```

Comment: Eu não tenho a certeza se o VB6 tem isso (VB.NET tem), mas experimenta a condição AndAlso em vez do And

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Essa avaliação de expressões lógicas é conhecida como "avaliação de curto-circuito" (*Short-circuit evaluation*): [Short-circuit evaluation](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avalia%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_curto-circuito)

Diferentemente do `C#` por exemplo, em `VB` não é executada essa validação, ou seja, numa sequência de operadores lógicos, todos são validados até determinar se a expressão é verdadeira ou falsa, assim por exemplo:

```
If a > b And b > a And b <> a Then
```

Em `VB.Net`, existem os operadores `AndAlso` e `OrElse` que fazem isso.

Aqui tem uma resposta do SO em inglês sobre esse assunto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014918/does-vb6-short-circuit-complex-conditions

As respostas confirmam que não existe o recurso em `VB6`, e as sugestões são fazer validação em blocos menores com `Then If` e `Select Case`

Leia mais (em inglês) aqui: [Short-circuit evaluation in Visual Basic.Net](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/817250/description-of-short-circuit-evaluation-in-visual-basic)

Comment: Interessante, achei que todas as linguagens implementavam isso!

Comment: Pois é, o `VB6` é uma exceção em muitas coisas